# Why does BitmapFactory.decodeResource with inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8 return a bitmap with Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888?

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I want to create a bitmap with ALPHA_8 configuration from 32-bit PNG image. To do that I call `decodeResource(Resources res, int id, Options opts)` where `opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8`. However, it returns a bitmap with ARGB_8888 configuration:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8;

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), id, options);

// Output: "bitmap.getConfig() returns ARGB_8888"
Log.w(tag, "bitmap.getConfig() returns " + bitmap.getConfig());
```

Why does it happen? How to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

because you source bitmap can't be decoded by ALPHA_8,so the Android auto picks the ARGB888 to decode.